# Single key shortcut in PyQt on a Mac?

Tags: qt, pyqt, keyboard-shortcuts

I can't get single key shortcuts to work properly in PyQt on Mac. For example, if I change the `QKeySequence` below to `Qt.Key_Tab` it works fine, but `Qt.Key_Control` doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

I've tried `Qt.CTRL` and `"Ctrl"` too, but they don't work either.

```
shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Control), self, self.show_dialog)
shortcut.setContext(Qt.ApplicationShortcut)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to test this myself, but the modifiers map to different keys on a Mac: see the note at the end of the [details section](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qkeysequence.html#details) for `QKeySequence`.

It looks like you need to use [Qt.Key_Meta](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qt.html#Key-enum).

Use this to see exactly which keys are being pressed:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.resize(200, 200)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print 'key: %s -' % hex(event.key()),
        print 'modifiers:', hex(int(event.modifiers()))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**EDIT**

NB: Qt does not allow modifier keys (in any combination) to be set as shortcuts.

Comment: `Qt.Key_Meta` didn't work either. I'll investigate further with your script.

Comment: So when I hit the `control` key, the `keyPressEvent` captures a `Qt.Key_Meta` key and a `Qt.MetaModifier` key modifier. Still no change though, no matter what I put as `QKeySequence` the shortcut still doesn't register. I will try the script in Windows to see if it's the same thing there.

Comment: I just checked on a windows pc too. Same thing there. The any modifier single key shortcut won't register.

Comment: @c00kiemonster. I assumed by "single key", that you meant something like `Ctrl+A`, rather than `Ctrl` by itself. Qt doesn't allow modifier keys to be used as shortcuts.